# Overriding variable value inside the $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a quite Strange problem, I dont seem to be able to override variable `jSonData` from inside the success function of `$.get()`

```
$.fn.name = function(data, options) {
        var jSonData = data;
        var settings = $.extend({
                ....        
        }, options);

        if(typeof data !== 'object') {
            if(settings.debug) console.log('Getting configuration settings from: ', data);
            $.get(data, function(d) {
                jSonData = d; //I attempt to override the value here
            }, 'json');
        }
        console.log(jSonData); // Gives the same value as it was before
};
```

<sub>**Note:** The success event of the $.get() is triggered</sub>

Comment: Isn't Ajax _asynchronous_?

Comment: @undefined It just slipped off my mind. Is there a way to solve this in a correct manner, without `setTimeOut()` or `setInterval()`?

Comment: @Starx: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @Starx: you haven't explained the original problem you're solving

Comment: @zerkms, I am trying to override variable value from inside the $.get(). The question elclanrs posted answer my question. I have voted this to be closed.

Comment: "I am trying to override variable value from inside the $.get()" --- it's not the task, it's a weird solution. Task is what you want to achieve with this code.

Comment: @zerkms, Oh! I am trying to create a way for JSON Object to either to be provided directly or loaded using a link which returns JSON output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you logged the value, the `$.get()` has not overridden `jSonData` yet since the AJAX request has not returned by that time. Do the `console.log` inside the function instead.

```
$.get(data, function(d) {
  jSonData = d; //I attempt to override the value here - You just did!
  console.log(jSonData);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this in a correct manner, without `setTimeOut()` or `setInterval()`?

Comment: @Starx: where do you see either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` in this answer?

Comment: @Starx: so why did you mention them then? And why do you think the solution isn't correct?

Comment: @zerkms, I have read about similar problem before, and the solutions were to check and wait for the data to return by the use of those functions.

Comment: @Starx: but this answer doesn't use it. It doesn't use hundreds of other functions available in javascript, and it's not the reason to mention all of them :-)

Comment: @zerkms, No it does not, so I asked Joseph, if he knows a solution `Is there a way to solve this in a correct manner, without setTimeOut() or setInterval()?`. See? :P

Comment: @Starx: he **already** provided a solution that doesn't use them. His original answer is a correct and doesn't use those functions.

Comment: @Starx Maybe you posted the wrong question. What do you hope to attain? Why not run code in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem because AJAX calls are asynchronous and thus the call would not have been completed when `console.log()` was executed.

Solution I used to fix my issue was by using deferring methods.

```
$.fn.name = function(data, options) {
    var jSonData = data;
    var settings = $.extend({
            ....        
    }, options);
    var getData = function() {
        if(typeof data !== 'object') {
            return $.get(data, 'json');
        }
        else { return jSonData; }
    };
    getData().done(function(result) {
        jSonData = result;
        console.log(jSonData); // Gives the same value as it was before
    }).fail(function() {
        //
    });

};
```